# Why I can not write directly those properties instead of "${xxx}" expression

Tags: java

Why coding like this?

```
private static final String MASTER_DATASOURCE_PREFIX = "master.datasource.";
//这么拼接的目的何在？？？
// Why directly write code like ‘master.datasource.jdbc-url’  instead of following codings
@Value("${" + MASTER_DATASOURCE_PREFIX + "jdbc-url}")
private String masterDbUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `master.datasource.jdbc-url` is easier to find in the project source base.

2) If you are introducing common prefix which you can edit to update multiple properties at once then there is better way

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "master.datasource")
public class DataSourceProps{

  private String jdbcUrl;
  private int port;
  // ... other properties
}
```